# Regex replace not working as intended on any browser except chrome

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a function which adds a styled span element around a regex match to create text highlighting within a code element.

I've managed to create a solution, however, it only works as intended on chrome or if the json form it not copied and pasted in. On other browsers such as firefox and edge, it styles text that I did not intend on styling. I have checked my regex using regex101 and everything seems fine.

```html
<pre>
   <code spellcheck="false" id="code" class="json" contenteditable="true">{
    "Id": "12345",
    "Title": "JsonForm",
    "Number": 1,
    "Text": "Text123",
    "Description": []
}</code>
</pre>
<button class="styled-button" onclick="highlight()">style</button>

<script>
  function highlight() {
    let block = document.getElementById('code');
    let formattedText = block.innerHTML;
    var text = formattedText.replace(/(\<span.*?\>|\<\/span\>)/gm, '');

    text = text.replace(/(".*?") *?(?=\:)/gm, "<span style='color: #7fdbca;'>$1</span>")
    //text = text.replace(/("[^\"\<\/\>\\]*?")(?=\,|$)/gm, "<span style='color: #ecc48d;'>$1</span>")
    //text = text.replace(/([0-9]*?)(?=,|$)/gm, "<span style='color: #F78C6C;'>$1</span>")
    block.innerHTML = text;

  }

</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/JacobShore/1xnkejma/22/
On browsers other than chrome, If you click the style button with the preset json it works, however, when you copy and paste the json into the code element and click style it doesn't. I am not sure what is happening here. I've commented out the other styled spans but they also have the same problem. I've added json for testing below.

```
{
    "Id": "12345",
    "Title": "JsonForm",
    "Number": 1,
    "Text": "Text123",
    "Description": []
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex for targeting the key-names was not working properly.
Also, since you're re-using the `block` variable, it's more efficient to save the selection.

```js
const block = document.getElementById('code');  

function highlight() {      
    block.innerHTML = block.innerHTML
    .replace(/(\<span.*?>|<\/span>)/gm, '')    
    .replace(/("[^"]*"):/gm, "<span style='color: #7fdbca;'>$1</span>:");
}
```

```html
<pre>
   <code spellcheck="false" id="code" class="json" contenteditable="true">
     {
      "Id": "12345",
      "Title": "JsonForm",
      "Number": 1,
      "Text": "Text123",
      "Description": []
    }
  </code>
</pre>
<button class="styled-button" onclick="highlight()">style</button>
```

Comment: Just an extra thought, do you know why .replace(/("[^"]*")$/gm, "<span style='color: #ecc48d;'>$1</span>"); won't style end of lines on firefox?

Comment: Without some research I can only speculate. Are you sure it works as you intent on other browsers?

Comment: Only works on chrome, the regex to detect the new line does not seem to work on other browsers. I can't seem to find another way of matching new lines. I tried the s flag with /n but that also only worked on chrome.

Comment: I just tried that regex in an online-test in firefox and it matched double-quotes enclosed strings right before a new-line. The issue might be that your regex removes the line-breaks: try adding one in the replacer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I managed to detect the line break by looking forward for the actual break tag /: *?(".*?"(?=,|$|\<br ?\/?\>|\}))/gm